# Reverse ssh for location distributed system behind firewall

Tags: ssh, firewall, tunneling

We have multiple machines located in different area behind firewall which don't have Static IP and can't be accessible from the outside.

We would like to access those machines but are wondering what the best option is. We thought about configuring a reverse ssh initiated by those machine to a central bastion.

But what happens if someone get access to one of those machine, go thought the ssh tunnel ? Can he access other machines thought the bastion ? Is there a best practice to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: My feeling is that, if you're having to think this hard about it, it's time for a proper VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ssh -R port1:host:port2 central` to setup tunnel then the tunnel allows connection initiated from central node only. Assume user has no access to the ssh session that setup the tunnel, and you didn't enable GatewayPorts in central node's sshd_config, or firewall on central node does not allow incoming connections, then you are good.

Have you thought about letting all these machines VPN to the centralized location? It seems easier and stable to me, and you can configure firewall to allow/disallow traffic.